# Kubuntu 20.04 Popping Sound brokem

Tags: upgrade, sound, kubuntu, 20.04, volume-control

after kubuntu 20.04 upgrade (from 19.10 on a Lenovo L580 laptop), it seems that popping sound (Audio Volume Settings -> Play sound when volume changes) does not work anymore: any feedback about this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake guys: from pavucontrol, Notification Sounds were turned off.